# Bootstrap 3: Stopping hover behaviour in mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following css code to make my header sub categories show on hover, which looks really great on the desktop version of the site, but looks terrible on the mobile or when the screen is reduced. What is the best way to make it stop using the following behaviour on a mobile site?

```
.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's simply the small form factor that these styles are problematic on, you might want to wrap them in the smallest Bootstrap media query breakpoint to ensure they don't apply to smaller sizes:

```
@media(min-width:481px){ /* hover rules */ }
```